# 10-game suspensions or 10 games suspension?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

> This athlete got a 10 game suspension for kicking an unconscious
> athlete in the face.

Is it 10-game or 10 games? I am not sure how to use this compound word adjective correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction uses the singular "game."

Because the adjective "10 game" modifying the noun "suspension" is compound, it requires a hyphen.

And finally, many style guides suggest spelling out the numbers twelve and below.

So finally:

> The athlete got a ten-game suspension.